# How to force display navigation menu injected with Object over orther div's (content)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wold like to make injected menu with  to be displayed over all orther content when using it.

Problem, when hover overmenu it cuts it when next div starts. in mobile version it also cut it from where next div starts.

Or how to do it easier? so it's always on top when displayed drop down or in mobile version ?

It all works when it in one file. but braks when injected with object. I want to have one menu file.

Index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title> ArniGotuje</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    <style>

    /* Style the header */
    .header {
    padding: 20%;
      background-color: #666;
      height: 300px;
    }

    /* Style the footer */

    .footer {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
    }
   

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Inject Nav menumob.html from files/menumob.html-->
        <div id="navbar">
            
            <object  data="files/menumob.html" name="menu" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ></object>
        
        <script src="files/script.js"></script>
        </div>
        <!-- Inject Nav menumob.html from files/menumob.html-->
        <div class="article" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h1>Topic</h1>
        <p>Ipsum pipsium.</p>
        <h2>Lore</h2>
        <p>Ipsum</p>
        


        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
        <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </body>



</html>
```

MenuFile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Designined by CodingLab | www.youtube.com/codinglabyt -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> ArniGotuje </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--Insert style for the rest of the site-->
    <style>
      

    </style>
    <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">ArniGotuje</a></div>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <div class="sidebar-logo">
          <span class="logo-name">ArniGotuje</span>
          <i class='bx bx-x' ></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="links">
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">HTML & CSS</a>
            <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down htmlcss-arrow arrow  '></i>
            <ul class="htmlCss-sub-menu sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Login Forms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Card Design</a></li>
              <li class="more">
                <span><a href="#">More</a>
                <i class='bx bxs-chevron-right arrow more-arrow'></i>
              </span>
                <ul class="more-sub-menu sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Neumorphism</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Pre-loader</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Glassmorphism</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a>
            <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down js-arrow arrow '></i>
            <ul class="js-sub-menu sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dynamic Clock</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Form Validation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Card Slider</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Complete Website</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="search-box">
        <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Css file for menufile.html - not for the index.html
cssfile.css

```
/* Googlefont Poppins CDN Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #3E8DA8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
}
nav .navbar{
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  /* background: red; */
  padding: 0 50px;
}
.navbar .logo a{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav .navbar .nav-links{
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 100%;
}
nav .navbar .links{
  display: flex;
}
nav .navbar .links li{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 14px;
}
nav .navbar .links li a{
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.links li:hover .htmlcss-arrow,
.links li:hover .js-arrow{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

nav .navbar .links li .arrow{
  /* background: red; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav .navbar .links li .sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #3E8DA8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav .navbar .links li:hover .htmlCss-sub-menu,
nav .navbar .links li:hover .js-sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu li{
  padding: 0 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu .more-arrow{
  line-height: 40px;
}
.navbar .links li .htmlCss-more-sub-menu{
  /* line-height: 40px; */
}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu .more-sub-menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
.links li .sub-menu .more:hover .more-sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.navbar .search-box{
  position: relative;
   height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.navbar .search-box i{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.navbar .search-box .input-box{
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% - 40px);
  top: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #3E8DA8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.navbar.showInput .search-box .input-box{
  top: 65px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: #3E8DA8;
}
.search-box .input-box::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #3E8DA8;
  right: 10px;
  top: -6px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.search-box .input-box input{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 35px;
  width: 280px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}
.navbar .nav-links .sidebar-logo{
  display: none;
}
.navbar .bx-menu{
  display: none;
}


/* responsive */
@media (max-width:920px) {
  nav .navbar{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 25px;
  }

  nav .navbar .logo a{
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  nav .navbar .links li{
    padding: 0 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  nav .navbar .links li a{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}


/* responsive */
@media (max-width:800px){
  nav{
    /* position: relative; */
  }
  .navbar .bx-menu{
    display: block;
  
  }
  nav .navbar .nav-links{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    display: block;
    max-width: 270px;
    width: 100%;
    background:  #3E8DA8;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .navbar .nav-links .sidebar-logo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .sidebar-logo .logo-name{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }
    .sidebar-logo  i,
    .navbar .bx-menu{
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #fff;
    }
  nav .navbar .links{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  nav .navbar .links li .arrow{
    line-height: 40px;
  }
nav .navbar .links li{
    display: block;
  }
nav .navbar .links li .sub-menu{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
}
nav .navbar .links li .sub-menu li{
  border-bottom: none;

}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu .more-sub-menu{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.navbar .links li .sub-menu .more-sub-menu li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.links li:hover .htmlcss-arrow,
.links li:hover .js-arrow{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  .navbar .links li .sub-menu .more-sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .links li .sub-menu .more span{
    /* background: red; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
  }

  .links li .sub-menu .more:hover .more-sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  nav .navbar .links li:hover .htmlCss-sub-menu,
  nav .navbar .links li:hover .js-sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
.navbar .nav-links.show1 .links .htmlCss-sub-menu,
  .navbar .nav-links.show3 .links .js-sub-menu,
  .navbar .nav-links.show2 .links .more .more-sub-menu{
      display: block;
    }
    .navbar .nav-links.show1 .links .htmlcss-arrow,
    .navbar .nav-links.show3 .links .js-arrow{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
}
    .navbar .nav-links.show2 .links .more-arrow{
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
@media (max-width:370px){
  nav .navbar .nav-links{
  max-width: 100%;
} 
}
```

Javascript for the menu:

```
// search-box open close js code
let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
let searchBox = document.querySelector(".search-box .bx-search");
// let searchBoxCancel = document.querySelector(".search-box .bx-x");

searchBox.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  navbar.classList.toggle("showInput");
  if(navbar.classList.contains("showInput")){
    searchBox.classList.replace("bx-search" ,"bx-x");
  }else {
    searchBox.classList.replace("bx-x" ,"bx-search");
  }
});

// sidebar open close js code
let navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
let menuOpenBtn = document.querySelector(".navbar .bx-menu");
let menuCloseBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-links .bx-x");
menuOpenBtn.onclick = function() {
navLinks.style.left = "0";
}
menuCloseBtn.onclick = function() {
navLinks.style.left = "-100%";
}


// sidebar submenu open close js code
let htmlcssArrow = document.querySelector(".htmlcss-arrow");
htmlcssArrow.onclick = function() {
 navLinks.classList.toggle("show1");
}
let moreArrow = document.querySelector(".more-arrow");
moreArrow.onclick = function() {
 navLinks.classList.toggle("show2");
}
let jsArrow = document.querySelector(".js-arrow");
jsArrow.onclick = function() {
 navLinks.classList.toggle("show3");
}
```

Comment: Figured it out.
  /* Set the z-index of the object menu to a high value */
#navbar object {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}

/* Set the position of the content to relative */
.article {
  position: relative;
}